# Диалог: допустима ли такая вот пунктуация в прямой речи?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, авторская-пунктуация, оформление-текста, диалог

Скажите, пожалуйста, верна ли (допустима ли) такая вот пунктуация в предложении?

*— "Завтра в полдень у Новореченской вас будет ждать... — Егор на секунду умолк и поднял на меня глаза. — ...Филипп".*

P. S.

Кавычки показывают, что персонаж читает с бумажки, многоточия — что реплика разорвана на 2 части авторскими словами. Такая конструкция (с учётом каждого знака) возможна или ошибочна?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (07.11.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20310076)):

> Достаточно одного многоточия. После слов автора можно поставить запятую, так как прямая речь представляет собой одну фразу, разделенную паузой, действием говорящего: *«Завтра в полдень у Новореченской вас будет ждать... — Егор на секунду умолк и поднял на меня глаза, — Филипп»*.

Answer (score 2):

С пунктуаций всё нормально. Почему возникло сомнение? Правда, я бы сказал, что многоточие скорее обозначает паузу ("на секунду умолк").

Answer (score 2):

— Завтра в полдень у Новореченской вас будет ждать... — Егор на секунду прервал чтение и поднял на меня глаза, — Филипп.

> Если на месте разрыва прямой речи авторскими словами должно было бы
> стоять многоточие, то оно сохраняется перед авторскими словами и после
> него ставится тире; после слов автора ставятся или запятая и тире
> (если вторая часть прямой речи не образует самостоятельного
> предложения, — начинается со строчной буквы), или точка и тире (если
> вторая часть представляет собой новое предложение, — начинается с
> прописной буквы): «Не надо… — сказал Вершинин, — не надо, парень!»
> (Вс.Ив.)

Было бы неплохо сделать паузу раньше: одно слово в отрыве от фразы выглядит странно.

— Завтра в полдень у Новореченской вас... — Егор на секунду прервал чтение и поднял на меня глаза, — будет ждать Филипп.

https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827535.html?ysclid=l7f6h66rn4787421319 (§ 49.5)

Comment: «Было бы неплохо сделать паузу раньше: одно слово в отрыве от фразы выглядит странно» — странно здесь выглядит единственно подобная претензия. Любой человек имеет полное право «оторвать от фразы» любое слово, если это ему зачем-нибудь нужно.

Comment: shampar, то есть вы предлагаете убрать кавычки, заменить точку с тире на запятую с тире и убрать многоточие перед "Филипп"? Без кавычек-то никак, раз он читает с бумажки...

Comment: @Егор Сальков  **«Если вторая часть представляет собой новое предложение, — начинается с прописной буквы»**, — так прописано и прописная после паузы сбивает с толку. И в этом имеется некая странность. Право плодить странности на ровном месте есть у каждого, и право обсуждать здесь эти странности странности имеет кто угодно.

Comment: @Shi Komarishe Без кавычек-то никак, раз он читает с бумажки... //// Задача решается текстом.

Comment: «Право плодить странности на ровном месте есть у каждого, и право обсуждать здесь эти странности странности имеет кто угодно» — так в чём дело? Продолжайте плодить, кто вам мешает!)

Comment: «так прописано и прописная после паузы сбивает с толку. И в этом имеется некая странность» — 
shampar, у вас в школе что, ещё не проходили, что предыдущее предложение вполне может заканчиваться многоточием?

Comment: Пыл умерьте, плз, товарищ Егор Сальков! То, что заканчивается, имеет в конце точку, а после многоточия ожидается строчная, и это естественно. А имя, как известно, имеет в начале прописную. Этого можно избежать, а можно и не заморачиваться. Кто-то ощущает неказистость, а кому-то она не мешает. Что до конкретного предложения: здесь многоточие не заканчивает предложение, если заметили.